# What is the story about NanoContainer in NEventStore?

Tags: c#, ioc-container, neventstore

Is the there a story behind the Nanocontainer Class in NEventStore ? 
Is there a relation dependency to other IoC's or is it written from scratch by the author of NEventStore itself ?

I ask this because I like the smart approach of this class, it seem's to be a very lightweight IoC container and very easy to understand.

If there is a unique package with only this functionality it would be fine.

Comment: Most likely proprietary, as [the project that owned the name NanoContainer](http://nanocontainer.codehaus.org/) during the great Cambrian Container explosion of the last decade is far heavier in nature than the one in NES. @JonathanOliver quick confirm please?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is one that only the developers of NEventStore can truly answer, but from the [available source code](https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore/blob/master/src/NEventStore/NanoContainer.cs) it is easy to spot that the implementation is very minimalistic and 'lacks' many features that make it a 'real' DI container. As far as I can see, the code is not really based on any existing container, although in basic all containers look alike.

The `NanoContainer` implementation is meant to implement just enough functionality that NEventStore itself needs or what a user needs when changing the default behavior of the framework.

It's open to discussion what features a DI library should have to be a 'real' DI container, but IMO it should at least be able to auto-wire types (where dependencies are automatically injected into a constructor based on the constructor's arguments). `NanoContainer` doesn't support this. Other features it lacks are:

- Batch-registration features
- Registration of open-generic types
- Support for (per request) scoped lifestyles.
- Unregistered type resolution.
- Registration of decorators or interception.
- Support for [releasing instances](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasepattern/) (disposing instances when done)
- Diagnostic tools to spot common configuration problems

Whether or not you need those features of course depends on a lot of factors.